# iPad app freezes but not on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, caching, ios7

I have an app which has started freezing at random when I run it on the iPad. It does not happen on any iPhone, not yet anyway. I download a bunch of images on my app, to display on a list, and store them to the internal cache in the background. Also, the app uses modal segues. The freeze is so random I am not able to pinpoint the source of the problem.

All this has started after the device was upgraded to iOS 7. I have also upgraded my Xcode to version 5 and am using iOS SDK 7. Everything was working fine on iOS 6.

Has anyone been facing similar problems?

Comment: Have you analyzed the running app with Instruments? I'd start with the CPU and Allocations instruments to determine what is going on.